# Activator.CreateInstance() creates an instance of a type but not affect reference

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a null object **qForm** and passing it to my **ShowFrom** method. The **qForm** object is instantiated inside the method but when it retun back I see that it is null. I expect that it should not have been null because it is already instantiated. Why it did not take effect?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should pass the form by ref: eg `private void ShowForm<T>(ref T form)`

Comment: You should pass `form` by reference, or return it from the method. Reference to object itself is a value type and you pass a copy of it to `ShowForm`

Comment: Also, please do not post code as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it did not take effect?

Because you pass a copy of the reference to the method rather than the actual storage location of the reference itself.

You can use the `ref` keyword to indicate that the parameter should be passed by reference:

```
private void ShowForm<T>(ref T form) where T : BsForm
...

ShowForm(ref qForm);
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) for more information:

> Passing a reference type by reference enables the called method to replace the object to which the reference parameter refers in the caller. The storage location of the object is passed to the method as the value of the reference parameter. If you change the value in the storage location of the parameter (to point to a new object), you also change the storage location to which the caller refers.